# Migrating iOS Project from Swift 2.3 to 3.0 in XCode 8

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have installed Realm Framework in my project(in XCode 7.3.1). But now after updating xcode to 8 i convert my project code to swift 3.0. and getting this error

Module file was created by an **Older** version of the compiler; Rebuild "Realm Swift", try Again

I rebuild, but could not resolve this error. 
So to resolve this issue, download latest Realm Framework from realm.io and replace older with new (swift 3.0).

Now i am getting this Error.

Module file was created by a **newer** version of Compiler.

please suggest me how can i resolve this incompatibility issue.

Comment: please check this out: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3796

Answer (score 4):

Xcode itself providing a option to migrate from swift 2.3 to swift 3.0. Update your Xcode to the latest 8.0 and here you go.

> Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax

there you have an option to convert which version you want!

hope this answer will help you!

Answer (score 2):

to manage the problem with Realm you had to change your Podfile and download last Realm version. Change pod 'RealmSwift' to pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true. And dont't forget to add at the end of your podfile

```
post_install do |installer|

installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|

target.build_configurations.each do |config|

config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'

   end

  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.1 isn't in Xcode yet, there shouldn't be any way you can cause a `Module file was created by a newer version of Compiler.` error if you're using Xcode 8 and Realm Swift built for Swift 3.

Make sure you're running Xcode 8, and the Realm Swift 3 binary. It might be necessary to completely remove all references to the previous Realm Swift framework in your app and re-embedding it from scratch to be sure.